# I have created a table using rhandsontable function now how can I update the table on submit button?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
 # titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    mainPanel(
     rHandsontableOutput('table'),
     br(),
     submitButton("Apply changes"),
     verbatimTextOutput('selected')
     )

)

 server <-  function(input, output) {
      data1 = read.csv("SampleCSVFile_2kb.csv", TRUE,",")


      output$table = renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(data1, width = 1000, height = 250))

      output$selected=renderPrint({
        cat('\nChanged Cell Old Value:',input$table$changes$changes[[1]][[3]])
        cat('\nChanged Cell New Value:',input$table$changes$changes[[1]][[4]])
      })
    }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the `input$table`? It's unclear what you actually want to update. Could you elaborate a little what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to update input$table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far from what I can understand you want to access the input of your rhandsontable inside your server when you press the submit button. 
In the example below I have modified your code so that I display the updated rhandsontable in `tableoutput`.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title # titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput('table'),
    br(),
    submitButton("Apply changes"),
    verbatimTextOutput('selected'),
    ##The updated table output
    rHandsontableOutput('tableoutput')
  )
) 


server <- function(input, output) {
  data1 = read.csv("SampleCSVFile_2kb.csv", TRUE,",")


  output$table = renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(data1, width = 1000, height = 250))

  output$selected=renderPrint({
    cat('\nChanged Cell Old Value:',input$table$changes$changes[[1]][[3]])
    cat('\nChanged Cell New Value:',input$table$changes$changes[[1]][[4]])
  })

   observe(
     if(!is.null(input$table)){
       output$tableoutput = renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(hot_to_r(input$table), width = 1000, height = 250))


     }
   )

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It worked. Thank you @SBista .  Can you explain hot_to_r function...??

Comment: @Ishanmahajan `hot_to_r` function is used to convert rhandsontable object to R object(dataframe).